# How merge a dict and a list and adding more value to it?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merging-data

we have this dict and this list

```
mydict={a:1,b:1}
mylist=[a,b,a,c]
```

I want to merge that list into the dict like this:

```
mydict={a:3,b:2,c:1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A companion to @meTchaikovsky's answer.

```
for item in mylist:
    mydict[item] = mydict.get(item, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
for item in mylist:
    try:
        mydict[item] += 1
    except KeyError:
        mydict[item] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Counters for this.

```
from collections import Counter

mydict={'a':1,'b':1}
mylist=['a','b','a','c']

c1 = Counter(mydict)
c2 = Counter(mylist)

mynewdict = c1 + c2

Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

If you need the newdict as an actual dict and not a counter then:

`mynewdict = dict(mynewdict)`